# Decrypting TitaniumBackup files

Tags: encryption, android-emulator, titanium-backup

I have TitaniumBackup encrypting backup copies of app settings before uploading to Google Drive. In order to verify/restore applications I need to type my password.

I need to extract a backup outside of TB. The problem is that Linux won't read the encrypted `.tar.gz` file. AFAIK TB uses asymmetric cryptography, which I don't know being supported by Linux file managers (or Ark application).

The question is: how do I extract an encrypted Titanium backup in Linux?